# Using HTML5 local storage

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a small site and having trouble to maintain the persistence of a cost value across the web pages.

I have tried using the Html5 storage but I can't get it to work.

Here is my Javascript:

```
function modifyPrice(cost) {
    // body...
    var total = document.getElementById('totalCost');
    var accumulte = total.value;
    var temp = cost + Number.isInteger(accumulte) + 15;
    total.value = temp;

    localStorage.setItem("priceTag",temp);

    document.getElementById('pricetag').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("priceTag");

}
```

And here's my sample html:

```
<span>
    <span name="price" id="pricetag"></span> $
</span>
```

Could it be the way I am executing **localStorage** or is there a better way?

Comment: What error do you get on the console? `#totalCost` is not defined in your HTML.

Comment: I am getting a return null ERROR at the last line document.getElementById

Comment: getElementbyId is null?

Comment: The way you are using localStorage is fine, I think your error lies elsewhere.

Comment: `getElementById` shouldn't be null for `#pricetag`, unless you have your JavaScript executing before the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Number.isInteger(accumulte)` returns a boolean result. So you have to change your code to something like

```js
var calculate = document.getElementById('calculate');
calculate.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var total = document.getElementById('totalCost'),
    accumulte = +total.value, // casting int to string.
    cost = 10,
    temp = cost + (Number.isInteger(accumulte) ? parseInt(accumulte, 10) : 0) + 15;
  alert("Value when accumulte is " + total.value + " = " + temp);
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="07" id="totalCost" />
<input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate" />
```

Comment: Adding a boolean to an integer adds a `1` or `0` depending on the boolean's value. I believe `temp` would be set to some integral value. The actual error may be something else.

Comment: You forgot parenthesis here. This will evaluate as `temp = (cost + Number.isInteger(accumulte)) ? val1 : val2`.

Comment: @JohnBupit: yep. I was meaning that the truthy falsy casting will yield wrong result anyway

Comment: @naveen, well no it's not mandatory, it just doesn't do the same : your code will fall on the first expression everytime `cost` is truthy. `1 + false ? 'val1' : 'val2'` returns '"val1"` while I guess what you want is `"1val2"`. In this case, it needs to be `1 + (false ? 'val1' : 'val2');`